# Responsive Navigation Menu Resize?

Tags: javascript, jquery, navigation, responsive-design

I am trying to build an extremely simple responsive navigation menu. Am having some problems here.

1. When I resize the window equal to or lower than 768px in width, the responsive menu
   will not work.
2. When I refresh the page at a lower window width equal to or less than
       768px, the responsive navigation works... But, if I resize even by
       one pixel, the responsive navigation display is hidden again.

I have created a CodePen here: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/fHsti

Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: You're hiding the menu when the window has a width less than 768px.

Comment: What is the desired functionality?

Comment: @showdev: The desired functionality is to have it work as a responsive menu.

Comment: @AlexMorrise: I notice that, but if I take out that else statement, it breaks the entire navigation.

Comment: @AaronBrewer Responsive menus can work an infinite number of ways. Your code "responds" by showing or hiding the menu. What is the problem?

Comment: @showdev: Resize your browser to a width less than 768px, try clicking on the "navigation" button. It doesn't work. Then refresh the page with the same low window width, the navigation works. Now try lowering the width of your browser, just as you would change the viewing mode on a tablet or phone to portrait or orientation mode. The navigation closes and you have to click the navigation button to display it again. These are the problems I am having.

Comment: Have you had a chance to look at this answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Honestly the best way to approach this is to only use JS for managing the state of the nav between media queries, everything else should be tucked away in media queries. Something like [MediaCheck](https://github.com/sparkbox/mediaCheck) or [matchMedia](https://github.com/paulirish/matchMedia.js/) is a great way to tie media queries and JS together.

I [created a simple demo](http://jsbin.com/eyuqes/1/edit) using your markup, and I think I got the functionality you were looking for. I used mediaCheck to clear away any JS-imposed inline styles between the main breakpoint of 768px.

Comment: This actually worked swell. Can you explain to me the difference between MediaCheck and matchMedia a little bit more? I looked at the documentation on github, but it was scarce to say the least. Thank you!

Comment: matchMedia.js is a polyfill for the [matchMedia browser API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.matchMedia). mediaCheck is a wrapper around matchMedia (the API, confusing I know) and provides a fallback for browsers that do not support matchMedia.

Answer (score 3):

Change this code. You need the `if` statement inside the event handler, otherwise it only binds the event if the width of the window is less than 768px on load.

```
jQuery("nav p.active").on("click", function(){
  if (jQuery(window).width() <= 768) {
    jQuery("nav ul").toggle("fast");
  }
});
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/BHbon

Comment: Thank you for this, but if I were to go from portrait to landscape mode, the menu closes. Thank you so much!